# Postgres SQL Query about database and table space

Tags: postgresql

What is the hierarchy of Database related objects in postgres SQL?
Should it be like, table space must be created at instance level unlike other RDBMS(where we have table space under database).
If so we create the table space at instance level, what is the purpose of database? and what is difference between table space and database on postgres server?

Answer (score 1):

An instance (in PostgreSQL called *cluster*) is a data directory initialized with `initdb` with a PostgreSQL server process.

A *tablespace* is a directory outside the data directory where objects can also be stored. Tablespaces are useful for certain corner cases like distributing I/O or limiting space for a subset of the data.

A *database* is a container for objects with permissions, organized in schemas.

The difference is that tablespaces are a *physical* concept, it defines a space where the data are stored, while databases are a *logical* concept about how data are organized, what they mean, how they are related, who is allowed to access them and so on.

The two concepts are *orthogonal*.
A database can have tables in several tablespaces, and a tablespace can contain data from several databases.

Comment: so as like other RDBMS, won't we have a table space under a database? .. because in other RDBMS like DB2, we will have in this hierarchy server->instance->database->tablespace->tables.

Comment: Right, it is different here. See the documentation.

Comment: at the end do you mean `data from several databases.` ??

Comment: Yes. I have fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`Database` is where you organize all your objects. `Tablespace` is just storage space for those object.

You can storage your db object in different `Tablespace`. For example one table is storage in a Tablespace in diskA but another Table use a Tablespace in diskB to improve the performance. Or maybe you need a tablespace for big tables and dont mind use a slow big HDD for those objects.